# In cocos2d's HelloWorld example, how come we don't use a HelloWorldScene but use a HelloWorldLayer?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I am a newbie in cocos2d, and wonder if layers are part of a scene, then how come HelloWorld is a Layer, but not a Scene?

It seems that it is a Layer, and then the class method `[HelloWorld scene]` will instantiate a scene, and instantiate a layer, and then return the scene to the caller.  I wonder why go down to the layer level, and then create a scene and add the layer to it, instead of making HelloWorld a Scene object, and then add a layer, and add a Label to it, in that order?

(It also looks like this may be good for letting a Layer object be able to be the only layer of a scene -- maybe it is a common pattern of cocos2d.)

Comment: The objective of a Hello World project is to get Hello World onto the display.

Comment: @MrSlayer that's the smartest comment I have heard in the past 30 years

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its just a matter of understanding the object oriented approach..

`CCDirector` needs a scene in the end.. It doesn't matter which class method I call..
scene method creates a `CCScene`, adds a layer to it and returns it back to the caller.. In the end layer is added onto scene.. That what matters...  Not which class method you are calling...

One can create a subclass of `CCObject` and mix all the stuff in it... Depends how you want to do that.. I do like you are saying.. ANd I feel comfortable in it.. :)